# wpf event handlers

Tags: wpf, event-handling, html.dropdownlistfor

I want an event which raises when the mouse leaves the control and goes to another application.  I have a customized dropdownlist which when opened remains opened even when the mouse leaves the control and enters another application. Hence the dropdown appears over that application.

Comment: Try to add relevant code to your questions, in order to receive better solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Mouse.MouseLeave event:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mouseleave.aspx

Comment: Its not taking care of the situation when another application is opened without even going into the comboboxitems but opening the list. As i have mentioned earlier, it is a customized combobox which has textbox and the listbox attached to it which opens when clicked.

Comment: @Laya : you need to think  which control you will handle the MouseLeave event. It may be the DropdownList, one of its component...  But MouseLeave should do the trick. Did you set the Background to Transparent ? might be usefull. Hard to say more without Xaml.